# Where do I download Oracle SQL*Loader for Macbook?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I saw quite a few sites saying that SQL*Loader is part of instanceclient now, but I downloaded instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip from Oracle download site, unzip the it.
All I saw was: 
`libocci.dylib`, `libclntsh.dylib`,`xstreams.jar`,`uidrvci`,`ojdbc8.jar`,`liboramysql12.dylib`,`libons.dylib`,`libocijdbc12.dylib`,`libociei.dylib`,`libocci.dylib.12.1`,`libnnz12.dylib`,`libclntshcore.dylib.12.1`,`libclntsh.dylib.12.1`,`genezi`,`adrci`,`BASIC_README`

Where do I download and install SQL*Loader? Thanks

Comment: This page: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html says that there are different *Instant Client Packages*. The one that contains SQLLoader is called **Tools** but - I don't see it in the list of ZIP files ... There are Basic, Basic Light, JDBC Supplement, SQLPlus etc., but no Tools. Is it possible that it doesn't even exist for Mac? I'm afraid I can't help, sorry; just shared some thoughts. Good luck!

Comment: Download the instantclient-tools-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip file from [the OTN Download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst)